# JSP can not find a class (class not resolved to type)

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP and server side stuff. I am trying to interact with database using servlets ans showing data using JSP pages.

First thing first, the BEAN and the DAO class do not belong to any package. I can compile my two servlets successfully and manipulate the data. But as soon as I try to use a DAO and BEAN class in a JSP file for showing data , it gives the said (in title) error.

I then copied the BEAN and the DAO .class in

> myservername\work\Catalina\localhost\myappname\org\apache\jsp

where all the JSP compile into servlets. Then this JSP could find the class and show me the data (this worked even if I deleted the .classes later on).

**Question is**: what is the best possible way to handle this. There must be a better way where I could tell the JSP where to look for the classes and I don't have to copy them manually in the said path (I am using notepad++ as editor) . Thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do such things manually. If you need some classes being used with JSP you can use JSP `page import` directive, but your classes should belong to some package, because this directive works on the package's classes.

> The import attribute serves the same function as, and behaves like,
>   the Java import statement. The value for the import option is the name
>   of the package you want to import.
>
> To import java.sql.*, use the following page directive:
>
> `<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>`
>
> To import multiple packages you can specify them separated by comma as
>   follows:
>
> `<%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*"  %>`
>
> By default, a container automatically imports `java.lang.*`,
>   `javax.servlet.*`, `javax.servlet.jsp.*`, and `javax.servlet.http.*`.